# Magento product availability in defined PIN codes only?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have a Magento based site and Products are limited to Set of Pin codes. These PIN differ from product to product. What I need is to get an option to input set of PIN Codes, while defining a product. And on every product page there must be a Text field to check whether the product is available for the PIN Code, which is entered by the visitor.

Comment: I removed the recommendation from your text and converted it into clear sentences, but it is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI For this  first of all

```
1 create a new product attribute with multi-select type 

2 assign all pin codes in there values under attribute options 

3 assign that attribute to the desired attribute set 

4 than for assigning attributes you need to go to product section and assign a desired zip options for that particular product from the multi-select attribute 

5 on product page you need to problematically get all the selected values of that attribute 

6 create a array of that values 

7 create a simple form and when user post some value in that form ,  match that value in the array you defined above. 

8 if the value finds in array than show the cart button and if not do what you want.
```

i hope this will give you a very fair idea. Let me know if i can do any other thing for you.

Comment: detail how to create a form in product view page for checking availability against that product in the supplied pincode, I Need a simple text field and button in the form

Comment: have you make the array of the options of selected pin-codes for that particular product on product page ? than after the form will work to match the post value in that array

Comment: there is no need to create plugin you create an array on view.phtml and place the form on the same file and compare the form value with in that array .are you familiar with coding